# NoClassDefFoundError(s) for org.eclipse.jdt classes while executing greenDao gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, greendao

I currently try to setup green dao to use in an android project.

I followed the instructions from the greenDao [github page](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO#add-greendao-to-your-project). I added the buildscript section and compile dependency and added the apply-plugin before the android plugin.

When building I get NoClassDefFoundErrors for some (not always the same) org.eclipse.core and org.eclipse.jdt classes. The stacktraces show that the errors occurs somewhere in the greendao generation process.

> :presentation:greendao FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   [...]
>   Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getOptions(JavaCore.java:3876)  at
>   org.greenrobot.greendao.codemodifier.JdtCodeContext.(JdtCodeContext.kt:15)
>     at
>   org.greenrobot.greendao.codemodifier.Greendao3Generator.

Not sure if this is related to greenDao at all. Maybe it is some gradle issue related to dependecy resolution? Tried to get gradle to print the buildscript classpath but didn't find a way to do that.

I think the greenDao configuration in general is correct. Checked it twice against the greenDao documentation. Can use the greenDao annotations in my code and the stacktrace shows that the greenDao plugin is run during the build at least tries to generate some stuff.

Any clues?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and your `build.gradle` file.  You can get it by building with `--stacktrace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution this morning:

My project is split into multiple modules. It seems that the buildscript part must be added to the root gradle script eventhough I need the plugin only for a single module.